# How to change LIBXML_NOENT default value

Tags: php, domdocument

How can I change the `LIBXML_NOENT` constant **default** value? (Or any other?)

Recently, I ran some basic php security audit script, and it is telling me, that this constant has default value of `2`, but should have `0`.